# Can we assign address to a pointer by another variable containing address of some other variable we want Pointer to point to?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I was trying to manually give address through another variable rather than using `&`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ab = 99;
    int *p;
    int f = &ab;
    p = f;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", &ab, p, f, p); // prints same address
    printf("%d\n", *p); // By adding this line, gives SEGFAULT
}
```

`./a.out` Gives:

```
284008584
284008584
284008584
284008584
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your compiler is obligated to issue a diagnostic message about this erroneous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the size of `int` and the size of `int *` is same, so that an integer variable can save the address without losing any data. Check this with below code:

```
printf("%lu, %lu \n", sizeof(int*), sizeof(int));
```

If both are not same, one can face the errors.

I will suggest take variable type `uintptr_t`, which can accommodate the pointer's address in it.

Comment: `long long` is almost certainly not the correct type for this. `long` usually is, but this is still not the greatest answer.

Answer (score 3):

You’re attempting to assign a pointer value to an `int`.  If a pointer is larger than an `int` on your system, which it most likely is if you’re running on a 64 bit OS, then you end up loosing data in the conversion.  When you then convert back you end up with an invalid pointer, and attempting to dereference this pointer causes a crash.

You’re also invoking undefined behavior by using the wrong format specifier to print a pointer.  You should be using `%p`, and you should be casting the pointer to a `void *` (one of the few cases when casting to `void *` is required).  If you do this the loss of data in the conversion will become apparent.

Comment: @ShreyashChauhan actually the proper type to use is `uintptr_t`.  This is guaranteed to be big enough to hold a converted pointer value.  You’ll also wan to use `%tu` to print it.

Comment: I think `%p` would be better. `ptrdiff_t` isn't guaranteed to be the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum, for GCC its `-Wall -Wextra`, if you like also `-pedantic`. Because:
2. There is an error int your line `int f = &ab;`. The expression on the RHS is an address of an `int`, but the variable on the LHS is an `int`.

On your system the sizes of integers and pointers might be different, that's why dereferencing a pointer which was set from an integer segfaults.

Comment: Dude, this just hides your error behind equal sizes. But it is still an error. The correct way is to change `f` into a pointer to `int`.

Comment: I know the correct way, I was just playing with the numbers and addresses

Comment: Well, it would have been nice if you had written that to save us the time to think about this issue. Please do so the next time. ;-) BTW, the correct way to print addresses is "%p".

Comment: Yes, I should have done that, I will take care of it next time. %d is just more readable than %p, anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the above correct answers about different sizes for pointer and integer,
if you modify your line which prints the addresses to use the correct format modifier, you will see the output addresses are different, due to the loss during cast from pointer to `int`:

```
printf("%p\n%x\n%p\n",&ab,p,f); // prints same address
```

Example:

```
0x7ffc8b716ea8
8b716ea8
0x8b716ea8
```